# SQL : join 2 queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a query for a friend's website. He wants to search a string in all his content (i.e. (sub)page title and content). Due to his database design, I had to make 2 queries (1 for the page title/content and one for the subpage title/content), because the subpages need some extra values (subpageID and pageID).

Is there a way to join these two queries in 1? It would make my code using this queries a lot easier :)

My knowledge of SQL isn't sufficient to deal with this myself.

```
-- Query 1
SELECT
    active, deleted, ID, page_ASP, page_title_EN, page_text_EN
FROM
    sub_menu
WHERE 
    page_title_EN LIKE '%europe%'
    OR page_text_EN LIKE '%europe%'
    AND active = 1
    AND deleted = 0

-- Query 2
SELECT
    sub.active AS 'active', sub.deleted AS 'deleted', sub.ID AS 'subPageID', sub.page_title_EN AS 'title',
    sub.short_title_EN AS 'shortTitle', main.ID AS 'pageID', main.page_ASP, sub.page_text_EN 
FROM
    sub_items AS sub
INNER JOIN
    sub_menu AS main
    ON sub.subID = main.ID
WHERE
    sub.page_title_EN LIKE '%europe%'
    OR sub.page_text_EN LIKE '%europe%'
    OR sub.short_title_EN LIKE '%europe%'
    AND sub.active = 1
    AND sub.deleted = 0
```

Comment: Are you looking for both query results to be returned in one data set?   If so, Union is the term you'll want to look for

Comment: You're joining the `sub_menu` table from the second query anyway, why not add the fields from the first query into the second query as well? You should also put the conditions from the first query into the second as well

Comment: Yell at your friend until he makes his table structure better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers on my question, I could find a working solution! Thanks for all the (very fast) help and here's the answer to my initial question.

```
SELECT ID AS  'Main ID', NULL AS  'subPageID', page_ASP AS  'ASP file', page_title_EN AS  'Title', NULL AS  'SubTitle', NULL AS  'short Title', page_text_EN AS  'Content'
FROM sub_menu
WHERE page_title_EN LIKE  '%test%'
OR page_text_EN LIKE  '%test%'
AND active =1
AND deleted =0

UNION 

SELECT main.ID, sub.ID, main.page_ASP, main.page_title_EN, sub.page_title_EN, sub.short_title_EN, sub.page_text_EN
FROM sub_items AS sub
INNER JOIN sub_menu AS main ON sub.subID = main.ID
WHERE sub.page_title_EN LIKE  '%test%'
OR sub.page_text_EN LIKE  '%test%'
OR sub.short_title_EN LIKE  '%test%'
AND sub.active =1
AND sub.deleted =0
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that for every active main page, there should be at least one active sub page...

```
SELECT
    main.active, main.deleted, main.ID, main.page_ASP, main.page_title_EN, main.page_text_EN,
    sub.active, sub.deleted, sub.ID, sub.page_title_EN, sub.short_title_EN, sub.page_text_EN 
FROM
    sub_menu AS main
INNER JOIN
    sub_items AS sub
    ON sub.subID = main.ID
WHERE
    (main.page_title_EN LIKE '%europe%'
    OR main.page_text_EN LIKE '%europe%'
    OR sub.page_title_EN LIKE '%europe%'
    OR sub.page_text_EN LIKE '%europe%'
    OR sub.short_title_EN LIKE '%europe%'
    )
    AND main.active = 1
    AND main.deleted = 0
    AND sub.active = 1
    AND sub.deleted = 0
```

If it's possible to have an active main page without sub pages:

```
SELECT
    main.active, main.deleted, main.ID, main.page_ASP, main.page_title_EN, main.page_text_EN,
    sub.active, sub.deleted, sub.ID, sub.page_title_EN, sub.short_title_EN, sub.page_text_EN 
FROM
    sub_menu AS main
LEFT JOIN
    sub_items AS sub
    ON sub.subID = main.ID
WHERE
    (
        (main.page_title_EN LIKE '%europe%'
        OR main.page_text_EN LIKE '%europe%')
    AND 
        (main.active = 1 AND main.deleted = 0)
    )
AND 
(
    (sub.active IS NULL) 
    OR
    (
        (sub.page_title_EN LIKE '%europe%'
        OR sub.page_text_EN LIKE '%europe%'
        OR sub.short_title_EN LIKE '%europe%') 
    AND 
        (sub.active = 1 AND sub.deleted = 0)
    )
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Your query works, but returns too many records. Subpages that doesn't contain the search string are also returned, when another subpage of the same main page does contain the search string.

Comment: Changed the condition, requesting that sub page either does not exist or conforms to your query.

Comment: Adjustment doesn't solve the problem... While debugging I discovered some more info.

The LEFT JOIN gives following result (excluded irrelevant columns):
main.ID | main.Page_ASP | main.page_title_EN | main.page_text_EN | sub.ID | sub.page_text_EN | sub.Title

Problem: if the search string is found in main.page_text_EN, the query will return all the subpages (because all those rows contain "main.page_text_EN". 

Should I tackle this problem in the SQL or in my code which will work with the SQL?

Comment: Ok thanks.

I've managed to get the desired result by doing a UNION of my 2 initial queries. A little bit of tweaking in my columns and it will work! (I will post the working solution when it's finished)